# How to make Jquery run only once on nested tags

Tags: jquery

I have a Small Jquery Snippet which is working rather wierdly...

Here is the jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").click(function (event) {
        alert(event.target.id);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">div1
    <div id="div2">div2
        <div id="div3">div3
            <div id="div4">div4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is the alert works multiple times on the nested divs. Why so?

Comment: Because click event "bubbles" to top most element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **[stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** : to stop the bubble

```
 $("div").click(function (event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
        alert(event.target.id);

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of bubbling and capturing use stopPropagation() method

http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

hope it helps you

```
element.onclick = function(event) {
   event = event || window.event // cross-browser event

   if (event.stopPropagation) {
      // W3C standard variant
      event.stopPropagation()
   } else {
      // IE variant
       event.cancelBubble = true
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `class` in that context

```
<div id="div1" class='myDiv'>div1
    <div id="div2" class='myDiv'>div2
        <div id="div3" class='myDiv'>div3
            <div id="div4" class='myDiv'>div4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery be

```
$(".myDiv").click(function (event) {

      event.stopPropagation();
      $(this).attr('id');

});
```